# Haskell error: Not in scope

Tags: haskell, compiler-errors

I am new to Haskell and I am stuck on an issue with compiler errors.  I keep getting the following error: src\Main.hs:26:22 Not in scope: 'threadDelay' when running the following code.  I thought it must have something to do with spacing or tabs since Haskell is really picky about that but I can't seem to find where my issue is.

```
eachMinute :: Bool -> Int -> [a] -> [a] -> String
eachMinute keepGoing num resevoir bin1 
    | keepGoing == False =  ""                             
    | otherwise = do answer resevoir bin1
                     threadDelay (1000 * 1000)
                     eachMinute keepGoing 0 resevoir bin1
```

Comment: Have you imported `Control.Concurrent`? (However, if `threadDelay` is in scope, you will get a type error for that code.)